# java.net is moving to Jruby?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

There is a post on http://kenai.com/ from Oracle's Ted Farrell which has an interesting statement:

> We are in the process of migrating java.net to the kenai technology.

Does this mean java.net will be powered by Jruby on rails??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If there is *one* thing that Larry Ellison *loves*, it's efficiency. Having two portals that do the exact same thing (project hosting) is stupid. Having them both powered by different technologies is even stupider. So, you take the bigger portal (java.net) and the better technology (Kenai), and throw them together.

Note that this is nothing new for Oracle: [Oracle Mix](http://Mix.Oracle.Com/), Oracle's community site has been JRuby and Rails powered for a long time, long before the merger. It is, indeed, one of *the* early flagship projects, which brought JRuby on the radar for a lot of enterprises. (The others are [ThoughtWorks Studio's Mingle](http://ThoughtWorks-Studios.Com/mingle-agile-project-management/) and obviously Kenai.)